# How to login jira through BOT?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api, botkit

Scenario :

I created a BOT (accessible via internet) using botkit which intercepts commands from CISCO SPARK and execute these commands on JIRA (on-prem). JIRA Server is configured with LDAP login.

Question :

I don't want to use the BOT account to access or login the JIRA server. 
I want to use the user's ldap credential to pass on from spark-> bot -> JIRA to use users credential to run the jira command.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use Passport-LDAP module to do LDAP authentication. There are other non-passport based LDAP auth modules too.

2) Once done you can use JIRA client module to connect to JIRA and perform your action. https://github.com/jira-node/node-jira-client